# Directory layout/structure for large iPhone/iPad projects

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, project, structure

This may sound like a bit of a silly question- but do any of you have any "preferred" methods of keeping a large iPhone/iPad project organized? More specifically, any type of strict directory/layout structures?

I know this question has been asked before in the context of something like an Xcode project- but what I'm wondering is what would be the best way to organize and keep an -entire- project clean and tidy. This includes other assets that are not directly used by Xcode, but otherwise exist as they are used to generate the assets that get included in Xcode (ie, Logic Pro tracks, Cinema 4D scenes, meshes modelled up in Modo, PSD and AI source files, etc...).

Some of our larger projects are getting a bit disorganized and difficult to make sense of, which is why I'm asking. I want to implement some sort of strict directory structure that everything will eventually adhere to (apart from the things already sitting in source control). We deal with multiple programs for the various assets that get used by Xcode to produce the final game- so it isn't unfortunately as simple as just tossing everything in the Xcode project folder and calling it quits.

Cheers,
-CMPX

Answer (score 1):

I like to follow a Rails inspired layout:

- App (AppDelegate and stuff)

  - Controllers (All the controllers)
  - Views (All your XIB's)
  - Models (All your models)
- Libraries (all Apple and 3rd party stuff)
- Images (static images)
- HTML (for local webviews and stuff)
- ...

Works for me :)

Comment: But this requires something like `#import "../Models/SomeModel.h"` in the Controller sources?

Answer (score 0):

For me, I keep two separate folders 1 for the Xcode project with all the final assets. The other folder external to the Xcode project folder is the art asset folder where I create all the graphics and later import them into my Xcode project.

In the Xcode project, I create separate folders for different types of assets such as classes and images, audio files, textures and so on.

Answer (score 0):

We found that separation as Apple suggests by default on models / views/ controllers (in different folders) is not sufficient. We are trying to keep structure workflow / functionality  oriented but flattening the structure of a project to keep all layers of an app visible for further code reuse. All XIB files usually kept in the same place with code files to make it simple to modify solution. All resources are divided by types at the top level and by workflows / functionality underneath.